# Is it possible to 'write' in Photosop (not TYPE)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

How do I explain this? Let's say I have an image of a person holding a piece of paper. On the piece of paper, I want to write with my own penmanship (not type with TextBox).

So the immediately solution is to write it on a piece of paper first, then upload it to Photoshop and paste it on that onto the original image.

Two problem arises.

1) Color of paper may not match. White paper have fades if you know what I mean

2) Very difficult to get letter by letter out on the new paper if writing is not good.

3) Resolution may be different.

Hence I would really like a solution where I can paste a TexTbox over the paper and for me to write on it.

Also printing out the picture and writing on it and then uploading it is not an option as I do not have a color printer.

Answer (score 2):

You could...

1. Use a brush within Photoshop and paint in the text you want....
2. Use a Digital Tablet to make handwriting easier than using a
   mouse... (probably cost prohibitive for just this)
3. Scan writing on paper, remove the (paper) background and place the writing over the photo.

Really a brush in Photoshop is just a brush. You could just as easily paint type as you would anything else.

If you are seeking some sort of **handwriting recognition**, there is **no such feature** within Photoshop. However, some operating systems have some basic handwriting recognition features. Whether or not they would suffice depends on what you need specifically and your Operating System features.